# How to fully remove Avast?

Tags: windows-10, avast

On windows, I've uninstalled avast via control panel but this popup still appears at the bottom right of my screen after logging in to any user.

[image]

I have searched all of my drives for 'avast' and deleted anything with it in its name.  How can I remove this pop up permanently?

UPDATE:

I have used avastclear, ran it in safe mode, and the popup still exists.

Comment: Avast offers a [cleanup tool](https://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility) on their website.  You should use that.

Comment: DCSofts' RegEditX is a pretty decent tool for removing all remnants of software you totally want to remove from your system. Even the uninstall routines of pretty much all software leaves pieces of itself in case you ever reinstall it. If you search "Avast", RegEditX will display all instances of that string in your registry. When I need to do this, I delete the entire key in which that sub-key appears. Good luck. (I'm not sure why someone downvoted this. It seems like a legit question.)

Comment: @BillDOe Question doesn’t have enough infrastructure to answer the question